# What is a sources JAR?

Tags: java

I was recently trying to import a library to use for something I am working on.

https://sites.google.com/site/piotrwendykier/software/jtransforms

I was having some difficulty because the JAR that I added to the build path was the "JTransforms-3.0-sources.jar" and not the "JTransforms-3.0.jar".

Now I am sort of scratching my head and just wondering what that first sources.jar was if it didn't have any of the classes that I wanted to use in it.

What is it and what is it for?

Answer (score 40):

That sources jar is a jar that contains only the source code (the .java files) corresponding to the compiled artifact. It is useful to add it as a source attachment in your IDE, to publish the sources, etc.

As it only contains sources, not compiled classes (.class files), it is of no use as a library dependency.

Answer (score 18):

**What is it:** Source JARs are the JAR file which contains only source code files i.e. `.java` files, and no compiled `.class` files. For example, you can download OpenJDK™ Source files from http://download.java.net/openjdk/jdk8/

**What is it for:** It is useful for other developers so that they can 'attach source' and debug into their project source code.

Comment: is there any app which ports from class JAR to source jar ??

Comment: @LOG_TAG There are several, they are called "java decompilers" and what they do it try to interpret .class bytecode into their original source form. However there are different limitations on doing this, so more often than not the source will not be as readable as you would expect, but could be useful anyways.