# Why do files in Selenium Java 3.14 zip show modified date as "2/1/1985"?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I am curious to know why does Selenium Java 3.14 zip files shows modified date as 2/1/1985 !

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a sources JAR?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30686312/what-is-a-sources-jar)

Comment: @Infern0 No. I am concerned with the modified date of the files inside JAR which is modified and released by Selenium in 2018

Comment: Good that you've noticed it. Why not report it to the Selenium team here? https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues

Comment: Thanks @BernardVanderBeken. Logged defect - https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/6564 Lets see what update i get.

Comment: From [github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/6564](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/6564): "This is expected behaviour. We use a build system that guarantees reproducible builds, and part of this process is normalising the timestamps in zip files."