# What are the differences between javadoc.jar, sources.jar and .jar?

Tags: java

Looking at Google gson 2.8.5 , I see several jars are distributed here https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/code/gson/gson/2.8.5/

- gson-2.8.5-javadoc.jar
- gson-2.8.5-sources.jar
- gson-2.8.5.jar

By reading other posts, I understand that **sources.jar** contains source code, but **jar** contains the compiled class files.

1. Does this mean that, given the sources.jar, I can generate the jar myself? What is the general relationship between these three jars?
2. What is javadoc.jar? Does it only contain documentation, or source code / compiled classes too?

Comment: with source code you can debug, with javadoc you can... well... read the documentation from your IDE

Comment: As a side note, if you're curious open them with a program that can read ZIP files and see what's inside.

Comment: Both files are intended for IDEs, where the `sources` files allows you to step through the code in a debugger, so you can actually see the source code you're stepping through, and the `javadoc` file allows the IDE to show you the javadoc of the classes and methods, while you're editing your code making calls to the classes defined in the jar file.

Comment: There is no reason to downvote this post. The question is clear and understandable, so it is possible to provide an answer. The fact that you expect everyone to know a particular thing is no reason to downvote!

Comment: Partial duplicate of [What is a sources JAR?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30686312/5221149)

Comment: @OP Welcome to stackoverflow. Please make sure you google before posting.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca Thank you, very helpful advice! I ran `jar xf gson-2.8.5.jar` and am now inspecting the content of the jars. Looks like `javadoc.jar` is neither a subset or a superset of the other jars: it contains just the HTML files, and no source/compiled code.

Comment: @Andreas Thanks for the link. While that post explains sources JAR, it fails to explain the difference between: sources JAR, javadoc JAR, and just JAR.

Comment: @KevinMaxwell Correct, the `xxx-javadoc.jar` file contain just the **javadoc** files. Same as the `-sources.jar` file contain just the **source** files. And the plain `.jar` file contains the standard stuff, i.e. the compiled class files (and resource and meta-data files).

Answer (score 9):

> Does this mean that, given the sources.jar, I can generate the jar myself?

Yes, you could extract the Java code from the sources.jar using the `jar` command.

E.g.
`jar xf gson-2.8.5-sources.jar`

And than compiling the Java files using `javac`.

But you need to have all the referenced dependencies in your classpath which are required when you call javac. These dependencies can be found in the project [pom.xml](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/code/gson/gson/2.8.5/gson-2.8.5.pom)

> What is the general relationship between these three jars?

The .jar file contains the compliled code which is contained in the sources.jar. So using the sources.jar you could create the .jar yourself (as mentioned having the required dependencies).
The javadoc.jar contains a static html site which content is extracted from all the javadocs which are present in the Java source files.